# Get base directory of current script

Tags: php

This is the url of my script: `localhost/do/index.php`

I want a variable or a function that returns `localhost/do` (something like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/do'`)

Comment: looks like you don't really know what you want

Comment: I know but my english is veryyyy bad sad :(

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
print_r($parts);
```

EDIT:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
 $dir .= $parts[$i] . "/";
}
echo $dir;
```

This should return `localhost/do/`

Comment: It is enough to use `dirname()`, which doesn't check if the directory really exists. The value returned from `dirname('/solar/system'`) is `'/solar'`, whatever the directory /solar exists, or not.

Comment: that's ugliest way I've ever seen. you've at least use implode

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does not contains the current script path when using url rewriting. That would not work in this case.

Comment: using implode instead of for loop is more elegant and convenient

Comment: This does not work with urls such as localhost:8888/do/index.php as it does not include the port.

Answer (score 35):

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: excellent answer, but this doesn't work on IIS unfortunately as dirname returns windows backslashes

Comment: actually it only returns a backslash if the request URI is localhost/do/ rather than localhost/do/index.php. I got around this by using the PHP_SELF which always includes the index.php, so `$current_dir_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Comment: I do not suggest using dirname(). At first: This answer is wrong, as it returns the parent and not the current directory, but even if you add a trailing slash (like @Your Common Sense did) you are facing a problem with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] as it contains only `/` if you call `http://example.com/`. By that `dirname()` would return `/` and as you add your second `/` it results `//`. You have the same problem with using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`. See my answer for further informations.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest not to use `dirname()`. I had several issues with multiple slashes and unexpected results at all. That was the reason why I created currentdir():

```
function currentdir($url) {
    // note: anything without a scheme ("example.com", "example.com:80/", etc.) is a folder
    // remove query (protection against "?url=http://example.com/")
    if ($first_query = strpos($url, '?')) $url = substr($url, 0, $first_query);
    // remove fragment (protection against "#http://example.com/")
    if ($first_fragment = strpos($url, '#')) $url = substr($url, 0, $first_fragment);
    // folder only
    $last_slash = strrpos($url, '/');
    if (!$last_slash) {
        return '/';
    }
    // add ending slash to "http://example.com"
    if (($first_colon = strpos($url, '://')) !== false && $first_colon + 2 == $last_slash) {
        return $url . '/';
    }
    return substr($url, 0, $last_slash + 1);
}
```

**Why you should not use dirname()**

Assume you have `image.jpg` located in `images/` and you have the following code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>../image.jpg" />
```

Now assume that `$url` could contain different values:

- `http://example.com/index.php`
- `http://example.com/images/`
- `http://example.com/images//`
- `http://example.com/`
- etc.

Whatever it contains, we need the current directory to produce a working deeplink. You try `dirname()` and face the following problems:

**1.) Different results for files and directories**

*File*
`dirname('http://example.com/images/index.php')` returns `http://example.com/images`

*Directory*
`dirname('http://example.com/images/')` returns `http://example.com`

But no problem. We could cover this by a trick:
`dirname('http://example.com/images/' . '&') . '/'`returns `http://example.com/images/`

Now `dirname()` returns in both cases the needed current directory. But we will have other problems:

**2.) Some multiple slashes will be removed**
`dirname('http://example.com//images//index.php')` returns `http://example.com//images`

Of course this URL is not well formed, but multiple slashes happen and we need to act like browsers as webmasters use them to verify their output. And maybe you wonder, but the first three images of the following example are all loaded.

```
<img src="http://example.com/images//../image.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/images//image.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/images/image.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/images/../image.jpg" />
```

Thats the reason why you should keep multiple slashes. Because `dirname()` removes only some multiple slashes I opened a [bug ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69263).

**3.) Root URL does not return root directory**
`dirname('http://example.com')` returns `http:`
`dirname('http://example.com/')` returns `http:`

**4.) Root directory returns relative path**
`dirname('foo/bar')` returns `.`

I would expect `/`.

**5.) Wrong encoded URLs**
`dirname('foo/bar?url=http://example.com')` returns `foo/bar?url=http:`

All test results:
http://www.programmierer-forum.de/aktuelles-verzeichnis-alternative-zu-dirname-t350590.htm#4329444

Comment: makes you think that dirname wasn't meant for URLs

Comment: too convoluted answer, takes too much code, better to use regex (see my answer); and if you fear a "wrong encoded url" you should just check using `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` and do nothing if it fails.

Answer (score 8):

php has many functions for string parsing which can be done with simple one-line snippets
dirname() (which you asked for) and parse_url() (which you need) are among them

```
<?php

echo "Request uri is: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "<br>";

$curdir = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/";

echo "Current dir is: ".$curdir;
echo "<br>";
```

address bar in browser is

```
http://localhost/do/index.php
```

output is

```
Request uri is: /do/index.php
Current dir is: /do/
```

Comment: @Snoob here goes your example. Now if you'll be able to explain what you're trying to use that "base dic" for, I'll tell you why it's not working

Comment: It works if url is localhost/do/index.php, but when i use localhost/do. Output: Request uri is: /ds/ Current dir is: \/

Answer (score 8):

When I was implementing some of these answers I hit a few problems as I'm using IIS and I also wanted a fully qualified URL with the protocol as well. I used `PHP_SELF` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `dirname('/do/')` gives `'/'` (or `'\'`) in Windows, when you want `'/do/'` to be returned.

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'off') {
    $protocol = 'http://';
} else {
    $protocol = 'https://';
}
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the server name, as I understood, then the following code snippets should do what you are asking for:

```
$result = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname(__FILE__);

$result = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . __DIR__; // PHP 5.3

$result = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) will give you the directory portion of a file path. For example:

```
echo dirname('/path/to/file.txt');  // Outputs "/path/to"
```

Getting the URL of the current script is a little trickier, but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return you the portion after the domain name (i.e. it would give you "/do/index.php").

Comment: echo dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); http://localhost/do/ => return \; http://localhost/do/index.php => return /do

Comment: To notice that if the URL is `http://localhost/do/index.php`, `localhost` is not included from the value returned from `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

Comment: @Snoob and @kiamlaluno: I already addressed this in my original post by saying `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return you the portion after the domain name (or, in this case, the server name).

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use the explode/implode function (built-in PHP) like so

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parts = explode('/',$actual_link);
$parts[count($parts) - 1] = "";
$actual_link = implode('/',$parts);
echo $actual_link;
```

Comment: makes no sense, regex can be used to do this faster and with less code

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion:

```
const DELIMITER_URL = '/';
$urlTop = explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim(input_filter(INPUT_SERVER,'REQUEST_URI'), DELIMITER_URL))[0]
```

Test:

```
const DELIMITER_URL = '/';
$testURL = "/top-dir";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);

$testURL = "/top-dir/";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);

$testURL = "/top-dir/test";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);

$testURL = "/top-dir/test/";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);

$testURL = "/top-dir/test/this.html";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);

$testURL = "/top-dir/test.html";
var_dump(explode(DELIMITER_URL, trim($testURL, DELIMITER_URL))[0]);
```

Test Output:

```
string(7) "top-dir"
string(7) "top-dir"
string(7) "top-dir"
string(7) "top-dir"
string(7) "top-dir"
string(7) "top-dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter (and correct) solution that keeps trailing slash:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_dir = preg_replace('/[^\/]+\.php(\?.*)?$/i', '', $url);
echo $url_dir;
```

Answer (score 0):

My Contribution
Tested and worked

```
/**
* Get Directory URL
*/
function get_directory_url($file = null) {
    $protocolizedURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $trailingslashURL= preg_replace('/[^\/]+\.php(\?.*)?$/i', '', $protocolizedURL);
    return $trailingslashURL.str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $file);
}
```

**USAGE**
**Example 1:**
    `<?php echo get_directory_ur('images/monkey.png'); ?>`
This will return `http://localhost/go/images/monkey.png`

**Example 2:**
`<?php echo get_directory_ur(); ?>`
This will return `http://localhost/go/`