# Get relative path to a parent directory

Tags: php, root, relative-path

I have a scenario where I want to get a path back to a specific parent directory. Here is an example folder strcuture (`[something]` is a folder)

```
index.php
[components]
    header.php
    footer.php
[pages]
    somePage.php
    [somePageSubPages]
        someSubPage.php
```

So my content pages look something like this:

```php
<?php
    include('components/header.php');
?>

<!-- CONTENT STUFF -->

<?php
    include('components/footer.php');
?>
```

This works for the `index.php` but not for `somePage.php` and `someSubPage.php`. What I want to do is create a function that returns the path back to the main directory so I can then add this to the includes and other stuff:

```php
$relPath = getPathToRoot($rootDirName);
include($relPath . 'components/header.php');
```

And the function only would return an empty string or `../../`.

I thought about using `__FILE__` and then just count the `/`-characters between the given $rootDirName and the the string end. However, I would like to ask if this is a reliable way and how this would look in PHP. (I don't realy work that much with PHP...)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429262/get-base-directory-of-current-script

Comment: where would you define such function? After all, you'd need to include the file containing such function, so you would be back to the original question.

Comment: I've noticed this dilemma :)

I think the line-count would be small enough to fit in the content-pages. Not elegant but should work.

@rahulmr, thanks. Somehow skipped this in the google search.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `..` to get into the parent directory:

```
<?php
    // somePage.php
    include('../components/header.php');
?>
```

Comment: OP want's a function that return `../` or `../../`

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that you always know the root of your site so that you can take it from there.

To do that, you could go at least two ways:

- Include a config file that defines your site-root and prepend that root to every include like (in case of a constant):
  `include MY_SITE_ROOT . '/path/to/file.php';`
- Use a server variable to achieve the same like:
   `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/file.php';`

Comment: Would work but I would like to not use an absolute path to my root just for portability etc. ;)

Comment: @ruhigbrauner I think a one-time setup (or server variable) is a lot better for portability and flexibility than using relative paths. Relative paths always get you into trouble sooner (like now...) or later :-)

Comment: The website is pure HTML with a bit of PHP for includes and conditions etc. So I will notice when there is a problem. :)
But you are right, I've also learned that relative paths should be avoided in real projects.

Comment: Just do `define('MY_SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));` in a central (config) file and you have the root directory (it is the root of the script in which the definition is). And always use absolute filepaths.