# Trouble moving path information to a query string in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I would like to rewrite `www.mysite.com/a/b/slug` to `www.mysite.com/a/b/index.php?id=slug`.

I am trying to capture the last segment of the path i.e. `slug` and use it in the query string -- similar to this [example](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewritePathInfo#Moving_path_information_to_a_query_string_-_intermediate).

So I have the following lines in my `.htaccess` sitting in my `public_html` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^a/b/([^/]+) a/b/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In my `a/b/index.php`, when I go to `www.site.com/a/b/slug`, `$_GET['id']` returns `index.php` opposed to `slug`. I am not sure why.

How can I capture the last segment and use it in the query string?

Comment: do you need the URL to look like `www.mysite.com/a/b/index.php?id=slug`  I would leave the URL alone, and just use `$_SERVER` variables and maybe RegEX to get your 'slug'.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429268/3790921

Comment: @Chad Thanks. I would consider that option but I found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add rewrite conditions in your .htaccess - at the moment, it is attempting to rewrite `/a/b/index.php` as well!

Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Thanks. I was about to reply the top comment that I found the same solution.